# Specflow Test Runner Naming Issues Displaying URL C# Using ScenarioOutline Examples

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, test-explorer, visual-studio-test-runner

I'm using Specflow Scenario Outline to run a list of different urls using Examples. However when checking Test Explorer the naming convention for each example is taking the last word after the full stop. I've tried finding something to do with formatting but run in to a dead end and couldn't find anything in here that matches my particular problem.

For example www.test.co.uk is showing as just 'uk in TestFeature'

Unfortunately in my test the URL is the unique value so when it comes to reporting it is clear what urls have been tested in the scenario...otherwise I would've used the Client name.

Packages in Solution include: NUnit, Specflow, SpecRun

Scenario Outline example below:

```
Scenario Outline: The login page for a given client is displayed when navigated to it
When I load the URL '<URL>'
Then The login page is displayed for client '<Client>'
Examples:
| URL                     | Client    |
| http://www.test1.co.uk  | Someone1  |
| http://www.test2.co.uk  | Someone2  |
| http://www.test3.co.uk  | Someone3  |
| http://www.test4.co.uk  | Someone4  |
| http://www.test5.co.uk  | Someone5  |
| http://www.test6.co.uk  | Someone6  |
| http://www.test7.co.uk  | Someone7  |
| http://www.test8.co.uk  | Someone8  |
| http://www.test9.co.uk  | Someone9  |
| http://www.test10.co.uk | Someone10 |
```

Test Explorer:

[image: Test Explorer View]

If anymore info is required let me know. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE and SpecFlow 2.4.1, SpecRun 1.8.5.

Comment: You should add the Specflow and VisualStudio version you use. When i paste your example in VS2017 i see "TheLoginPageForAGivenClientIsDisplayedWhenNavigatedToIt_HttpWww_Test1_Co_Uk" as the name used.

Comment: @jeroenHeir Thanks - updated. Looks like your example is formatting the fullstops as underscores...Do you know how to modify this as that might be my solution?

Comment: See [this](https://specflow.org/documentation/Generating-Step-Definition-Skeletons/) page: can change the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue - I updated my app.config to include <trace stepDefinitionSkeletonStyle="MethodNameUnderscores" />, then recreated the step definitions and a new dummy scenario but the naming of my examples still persisted. Can you advise what default style you have in your app.config? Also what test runner are you using?

Comment: I am not using any config at all; the naming convention mentioned earlier is the default. I am using C#, .NetCore 2.2, Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation (3.0.155-beta), VS2017 and the Specflow for VS2017 extension 2018.1.15.7173 (add an additional extension gallery under options): https://www.myget.org/F/specflow-vsix/vsix ). See also [here](https://specflow.org/2018/net-core-support-specflow/)

Answer (score 0):

We (as in SpecFlow+ Team) have a bug in the escaping of scenario names when they contain a dot. We still need to fix it.

What I would suggest you, (and is the quickest workaround at the moment), is to add a column add the start and use it to describe the single example in this row.

SpecFlow is using the first column of a scenario outline column for the naming. If you only have urls, the scenario names aren't that good to read. And the urls are an "implementation" detail.
Perhaps the client name is better suited to be included in the scenario name.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the SpecFlow & SpecFlow+ developers.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWillich for the feedback. Looking forward to the fix. Unfortunately in my scenario a single client can have multiple urls, urls being the main distinguishing identifier for the test. Just the way the data is I'm afraid. I can potentially change the dataset but in the end it is also down to the business I work for to determine the dataset.

Comment: @Scott: Could you create an issue here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow 
I tried to reproduce the issue, but I wasn't able to. In this example https://github.com/SabotageAndi/SpecFlow.Example.AllTestRunners/blob/master/SpecFlow.Plus.Runner/SpecFlowFeature1.feature the scenario name is displayed correctly.